# Locks with multiple threads parallel programming in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, locking

How to answer this? please help.

Consider the following program with 3 threads.

```
locks l1, l2, l3;
```

*Thread 1

```
while(1){

l1.lock();

l2.lock();

printf(“Red”);

l3.unlock();

l1.unlock();}
```

*Thread 2

```
while(1){

l2.lock();

l3.lock();

printf(“Green”);

l1.unlock();

l2.unlock();}
```

*Thread 3

```
while(1){

l3.lock();

l1.lock();

printf(“Blue”);

l2.unlock();

l3.unlock();}
```

a) What are the possible outcomes of the above program. Can you explain how this'll happen?
b) Will this code lead to a deadlock?

Comment: Locks is an abtract concept, but can you specify the definition of your type: 'locks'?; this maybe can be usefull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382122/whats-the-difference-between-mutex-and-lock

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what `l1.lock()`, `l1.unlock()`, etc., actually do. Since this is tagged C++ (although the title says C), if these function calls are managing `std::mutex` objects, the result is undefined behavior, with each thread unlocking a mutex that it didn't lock.

Comment: sorry since im actually very much new to these.so can you explain those for me a bit more please?

Comment: The rule for mutexes in C++ is that the only thread that's allowed to unlock a mutex is the one that locked it. But since you've already accepted another  answer, I don't see any point in further discussion.

Comment: I don't know what you meant by accepted another answer. Im new to here.but anyway it'll be very helpful if you can further explain please

Comment: That green checkmark (that you've now removed) means you accepted the answer as the right solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of readibly, I'll refer to locks as an array (eg. `lock[0], lock[1], lock[2]`)

A) Depends on which thread starts executing first.

1. If thread 1 starts first: Red, Blue, Green, Red, Blue, ...
2. If thread 2 starts first: Blue, Green, Red, Blue, Green, ...
3. If thread 3 starts first: Green, Red, Blue, Green, Red, ...

B) Yes, it can. And it probably will. Consider it:

1. Thread 1 locks `lock[0]`
2. Thread 2 locks `lock[1]`
3. Thread 3 locks `lock[2]`
4. Thread 1 try to lock `lock[1]`, waiting for thread 2
5. Thread 2 try to lock `lock[2]`, waiting for thread 3
6. Thread 3 try to lock `lock[3]`, waiting for thread 1

Comment: can you explain how it can switch between threads? im not clear on it

Comment: On real computers, it can appear completely random as it completely depends on scheduler (which is usually part of the OS). There's really nothing more to say, since nowdays computers are multicore, which means threads would actually run parallel.

Comment: For further reading, I would suggest <a href="https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)">Wikipedia</a>

Comment: its too much :(  need specifically answer for this

Comment: Like I said, you should consider that threads are impossible to predict - it can execute pretty much anytime as long as it's alive. For example, your code may or may not catch itself inside a deadlock, because if your OS decides to switch threads every loop (of your code), it works normally. But if OS switches thread while a thread has locked only one mutex, it will cause deadlock. (to solve this problem, you need to insert a global mutex that surrounds locking two mutexes)